# If $\tau(\sum P_i) =\infty$, can we find a sequence of projections $\{Q_n\}$ from $\{P_i\}$ such that $\tau(\sum Q_n) =\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let ${P_i}$ be a family of mutually orthogonal projections of a semifinite von Neumann algebra $M$ and $\tau$ be the semifinite faithful normal trace on $M$. If $\tau(\sum P_i) =\infty$, can we find a sequence of projections $\{Q_n\}$ from $\{P_i\}$ such that $\tau(\sum Q_n) =\infty$?

My idea is:

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\tau(P_i)<\infty$ for every $i$.
Define $\alpha_i := \tau(\sum_{j\le i} P_j)$. Then, since $\tau$ is normal, we have $\sup_i\alpha_i = \sup_i\tau(\sum_{j\le i} P_j)=\tau( \sup_i \sum_{j\le i} P_j) =\tau( \sum P_j) =\infty  $. 
Since $\tau(P_i) >0$ for every $i$ ($\tau$ is faithful), the elements in $\{\alpha_i <\infty\}$ are distinct and therefore $\{\alpha_i <\infty\}$ consists of countably many elements. But I don't know how to show the supremum of $\{\alpha_i <\infty\}$ is infty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\tau$ is normal, we have $\tau(\sum P_i)=\sum \tau(P_i)$. So this becomes a question about numbers.

If $\{\alpha_j\}\subset[0,\infty)$ satisfies $\sum_j\alpha_j=\infty$, this means by definition that 
$$
\sup\{\sum_{j\in F}\alpha_j:\ F \text{ finite}\}=\infty
$$
So we can find finite subsets $F_n$ such that $\sum_{F_n}\alpha\geq n$. Let $E=\bigcup_n F_n$. Then $E$ is countable and, for each $n$,
$$
\sum_E\alpha_j\geq\sum_{F_n}\alpha_j\geq n,
$$
so $\sum_E\alpha_j=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that there is no such a subset $\{P_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\{P_i\}_i$ consisting of countably many projections such that $\tau(\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n )=\infty$.
Then, there is a finite constant $C>0$ such that, for every subset $\{P_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\{P_i\}_i$ consisting of countably many projections, $\tau(\vee_{n=1}^\infty P_n) \le C$ (Otherwise, for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a subset $S_k:=\{P_{kn}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\tau(\vee _{n=1}^\infty P_{kn})>k $. Let $S=\vee_{k=1}^\infty S_k$. Then, $S$ consists of countably many projections  from $\{P_i\}_i$ and $\tau(\vee_{P\in S} P ) \ge \tau(\vee_{P\in S_k } P ) >k$ for every $k$. That is, $S$ is the set we need.).

Define $\bar{S}:=\{\mbox{$S$ consisting of countably many projections from $\{P_i\}_i$} \}$ and $ M:= \{ \tau(\vee_{P\in S} P  )\mid S\in \bar{S} \} $.
Then, every element from $M$ has a upper bound $C$ and therefore the supremum $\bar{C}$ of $M$ is less than $C<\infty$. 
For every $n$, we can find an $S_n\in \bar{S}$ such that $\tau(\vee_{P\in S_n} P  ) \ge \bar{C} -\frac{1}{n}$.
Then, $\vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n \in \bar{S}$ with $\tau(\vee_{P\in \vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n  } P  ) \ge \tau(\vee_{P\in  S_n  } P  ) \ge \bar{C}-\frac1n $ for every $n$. 
Hence, $\tau(\vee_{P\in \vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n  } P  ) \ge \bar{C}$. 
However, since $\tau$ is faithful, $\tau(P_i)>0$ for every $P_i \in \{P_i\}$. 
We only need to take an $Q \in \{P_i\} \setminus  \vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n $ (If it is empty, then $\tau(\sum P_i) =C <\infty$, which is a contradiction.).
Then, $\{Q\} \vee  ( \vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n) \in \bar{S} $ consists of countably many projections with $ \tau(\{Q\} \vee  (\vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n ) ) = \tau(Q) +\tau(  \vee_{n=1} ^\infty S_n ) > \bar{C} $, which is a contradiction to that $\bar{C}<\infty $ is the supremum of $M$.